letting someone down (when playing bridge)
I am translating W Somerset Maugham's 'The Three Fat Women of Antibes'. There are a few terms about bridge, and I suspect this is one of them:

They had always been fond of talking over their hands, but their discussions had been friendly. Now a distinct bitterness crept in and sometimes one pointed out a mistake to another with quite unnecessary frankness. Discussion turned to argument and argument to altercation. Sometimes the session ended in angry silence. Once Frank accused Arrow of deliberately letting her down. Two or three times Beatrice, the softest of the three, was reduced to tears. On another occasion Arrow flung down her cards and swept out of the room in a pet. Their tempers were getting frayed. Lena was the peacemaker.

The usual definition of "letting sb. down" doesn't seem to apply here, too.
So my question is, what does it mean when you let someone down in bridge? Or perhaps I'm wrong in assuming it's a jargon? If so, what does the phrase mean here?

What does your dictionary say it means? Cambridge's definition - "to not do something that you promised to do" - would apply quite well to bridge. Do you know the basics of bridge, about playing in couples and bidding for contracts?

'[Deliberately] not playing to the best of one's ability.' Throwing the game.

@StuartF I don't know anything about bridge. I know the definition you quoted, but in that case, what is it that she promised to do? That what I have difficulty understanding.

@EdwinAshworth thank you. So Frank felt Arrow didn't do her best and felt disappointed towards her?

Yes; when there's a tense situation, it's all too easy for F to read ill intention into the underperformance of some player on one's team, when it might rather be largely caused by the pressure not to fail that that player is under because of the demanding attitude of F.

It has to do with their conversation (talking over their hands) and feelings, not necessarily about the game per se. Although that is slighlty ambiguous.

Bridge is a partnership game, so your own success requires that your partner also succeeds, and cooperates in your strategy in the game. Since you're depending on your partner doing things correctly, if they do something wrong it can be seen as letting you down.
However, it's unusual to let someone down intentionally in a partnership game like bridge, since you also lose. This type of thing happens more in other areas of life. For instance, if you promised to drive someone to the airport, and cancel at the last minute with no good excuse, that's letting them down intentionally.
But even so, Frank and Beatrice might feel like Arrow misplayed intentionally out of spite for some reason. These kinds of things aren't always logical.
